The XCUI performance tests ignore the baseline target
I'm using Xcode native performance test tool, Measure().
Described here:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xctestcase/3194266-measure
The issue is after you initially run the test you set then baseline threshold. Afterwards, each time it's executed it will fail then test if it exceeds the maximum threshold.
However, even when I set the baseline I see a popup stating the baseline has not been set.  And the test does not fail if it exceeds the maximum baseline.
My online search shows that others using XCode 15.2 have also experienced this issue.  I'm someone knows of a work-around so that my tests will fail if they don't meet the baseline.
Thank you
